# get the script path with whitespaces in Bash

Tags: bash, directory

I'm running it under MacOS El Capitan 10.10.6

among all commands to get my current dir (path I'm running my script from) only this works for me:

```
FILES="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
```

But it's not going to work if the folder has whitespace in it's name (aka: "folder name")

How to fix this?

Thank you! )

**Update: added a script:**

```
    #!/bin/bash

function check ()
{
oldsize=`wc -c <"$1"`
sleep 1
newsize=`wc -c <"$1"`

while [ "$oldsize" -lt "$newsize" ]
do
 echo "Not yet..."
oldsize=`wc -c <"$1"`
sleep 1
newsize=`wc -c <"$1"`
done

if [ "$oldsize" -eq "$newsize" ]
then
   echo "The file has been copied completely."
fi
}


FILES="$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")/*"


function main
{

for f in $FILES
do

if [[ "$f" =~ \.mkv$ ]];
then
#/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 check "$f"
 (( count = count + 1 ))
 g="${f/mkv/avi}"

 #LOG_FILE="${g/avi/log}"

 #exec > >(tee -a "${LOG_FILE}" )
 #exec 2> >(tee -a "${LOG_FILE}" >&2)

 now="$(date)"
 printf "Current date and time %s\n" "$now"

   echo "Processing $f file..."

   #avconv -i "${f}" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -codec copy -sn "${g}"
   avconv -i "$f" -map 0 -codec copy "$g"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo OK
    rm "$f"
else
    echo FAIL
    rm "$g"
    #rm "$LOG_FILE"
    return
fi

fi
#/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

done

}

############
count=0
############

main

if (($count > 0)); then
open "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"
fi

exit
```

Comment: You mean [*whitespace*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)?

Comment: Are you looking for the directory that holds the source of the script, or for the current directory of the process running the script? Your terminology is a little confusing.  What was wrong with just `DIRECTORY="$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"` (that's a lot of quotes and brackets).  Note that the `cd` in your command is run in a sub-shell and hence does not affect the parent shell process.

Comment: I want to get a directory the script is running from

Comment: What do you mean by "the script is running from"?  It is at best ambiguous; at worst, meaningless.  Do you mean "the directory containing the source code of the script that is running"?  Or do you mean "the current directory of the process that is running the script"?

Comment: I'm putting the script (.sh file renamed to .command (OS X version of Windows's bat)) inside a folder which contains files that I want my script to process (operate on).. that is why I need to get my current path first.. **"$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"** WORKS but only if there isn't any whitespaces..

Comment: Do you quote `FILES` when you later use it?

Comment: Well, I don't know what you're doing wrong, but I've just shown that for me, the `$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")` command works fine.  Do you remember to always quote the variable you assign that to?  With spaces in the path, you must always quote your file names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Mac OS X 10.11.6, and I have a directory `$HOME/tmp`.  From there, I executed:

```
$ cd $HOME/tmp
$ pwd
/Users/jleffler/tmp
$ mkdir -p "Spaced Out  Directory   "/bin
$ export PATH="$PATH:$PWD/$_"
$ cat <<'EOF' > Spaced\ Out\ \ Directory\ \ \ /bin/gorblinsky.sh
> #!/bin/bash
> 
> echo "PWD=$PWD"
> DIR="$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"
> echo "DIR=$DIR"
> cd "$DIR"
> pwd
> echo "PWD=$PWD"
> EOF
$ chmod +x Spaced\ Out\ \ Directory\ \ \ /bin/gorblinsky.sh 
$ gorblinsky.sh
PWD=/Users/jleffler/tmp
DIR=/Users/jleffler/tmp/Spaced Out  Directory   /bin
/Users/jleffler/tmp/Spaced Out  Directory   /bin
PWD=/Users/jleffler/tmp/Spaced Out  Directory   /bin
$
```

This shows that the command `$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")` can determine the name of the directory where the source for the command is stored.

If the script was going to use the variable `$DIR` to specify file names, you'd need to be careful (very careful) to ensure it is always properly quoted.

For example:

```
cp "$DIR/gorblinksky.h" "$HOME/tmp/cobbled together name"
```

Modern style is to always (double) quote all variable references, even when there's nothing in them that needs protecting (see [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net/) for example — and [Google Shell Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml)).  I'm old-school enough not to put quotes around names that can't contain spaces or metacharacters, but I guess that is just old-fashioned. For example, I shell-checked a script for playing with RCS version numbers, and it doesn't quote variables containing dotted strings of digits (9.19.2.24 — could be an IBM IPv4 address too) and I was told off for not quoting them, though the file names were already protected with quotes.

Comment: Maybe the quotes in `cd "$DIR"` were missing in the original script we haven't seen?

Comment: @choroba: that has to be my best guess too.